# Array group by name in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a list of orders in XML and I need to list the products and the quantities group by name to show a list like:

```
     <ul>
     <li>Product name A - 3</li>
     <li>Product name B - 6</li>
     <li>Product name C- 3/<li>
     </ul>
```

I read the XML and I created an Array with foreach like this:

```
 foreach($order->associations->order_rows as $product){

        $list[]=[
            'name' => $producto->product_name,
            'quantity' =>$producto->product_quantity
        ];

  }
```

And the array is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Kong - Size : M (39-42)
            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Kong - Size : M (39-42)
            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Invaders - Size : M (39-42)
            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Super Mamá - Size : S (35-38)
            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Vanlife - Size : M (39-42)
            [quantity] => 1
        )
```

I need to show on the front the quantity for each product (Array group by name).

I'm trying to use a Collection

```
$namelist = collect($list)->groupBy('name');
```

But I'm not sure what is the best way to do it and I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

One option is to loop through all the items and sum the quantity for the same name.

If you don't need the intermediate `$list`, you can also sum the quantity in the foreach loop directly.

For example

```
$results = [];

foreach ($list as $item) {
    array_key_exists($item["name"], $results) ?
        $results[$item["name"]]["quantity"] += $item["quantity"] :
        $results[$item["name"]] = $item;
}

echo "<ul>" . PHP_EOL;;
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo sprintf("<li>%s - %s</li>", $result["name"] , $result["quantity"]) . PHP_EOL;
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Output

```
<ul>
<li>Kong - Size : M (39-42) - 2</li>
<li>Invaders - Size : M (39-42) - 1</li>
<li>Super Mamá - Size : S (35-38) - 1</li>
<li>Vanlife - Size : M (39-42) - 1</li>
</ul>
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/Oqdbi)